# .htaccess redirected you too many times

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ip

I need some help please

I have installed LAMP on my Debian 7.1 VPS and there's no domain, just an IP.

When I try access my IP via browser, it says:

```
The [ive hidden the IP] page isn’t working
[ive hidden the IP] redirected you too many times.
```

I'm not exactly sure what to edit/remove in my .htaccess file to fix this.

This is what my .htaccess file looks like

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(\w+)+\/$ index.php?page=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

order allow,deny
deny from [some random ip address that i've hidden]
allow from all
```

I've removed www. from the last RewriteRule line because I'm using an IP address instead of a domain, did I do this correctly?

Thanks

Comment: Best thing to do is to start by commenting out sections of your `.htaccess` code to find out where the problem is originating from. Once we know which section is causing the issue, then look at sorting a fix.

Comment: It will be hard for me to do that because the .htaccess file came with the template that I am using :(

Comment: Your template does not allow you access to edit it?

Comment: Yeah I can edit it, I've removed the www. from:

RewriteRule ^ http%1://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

Because I'm using a VPS with no domain.

Comment: OK, so you're saying you're getting the error since removing that piece of code from your .htaccess?

Comment: Sorry yes, basically, the URL was listing as www.IP address/ (example: www.111.222.333.444/. So I had to remove the www. from the .htaccess, then I restarted apache on Debian, then it said this error that I'm getting now.

Comment: Ah I see, you've changed the `Rewrite`, but left the `RewriteCond` that is still checking for www. Try removing the line: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]` and then see what happens when you run it.

Comment: Ok I just tried that now, still getting the same error.

Comment: Did you have this error before you removed the www from the `RewriteRule`?

Comment: Before I removed the www. It still wouldn't work because the www.1.2.3.4/ was an invalid URL. Once I removed the www. it seems to find the directory but I think it's redirecting to many times, maybe something a command is overwriting (I'm guessing, I'm a noob at this sorry). I also created a sub folder in my /www/ folder, pasted a index.html to test and it works fine. Oh yes I don't know if this is important information but the site I'm trying to access is in another sub folder called 'site1'. (example: /www/sub1/

Comment: Can you comment out the remainder of your .htaccess please. Run it. If it is then working, un-comment sections until we find the exact part that is causing the issue.

Comment: Ok I tried this now, didn't seem to fix anything. :( It just kept saying the same error message, I even cleared my cache and cookies.

Comment: @thickguru I managed to get it working, I just decided to get a domain and restart apache then upload/overwrite the default .htaccess that came with the template. All is good now. Thank you very much for the effort. I really appreciate it! Keep well mate!

Comment: Great news Robby. Glad you managed to figure it out. Sorry I couldn't help as I'd hoped. Don't hesitate to ask any more questions :)